# Extracting data directly from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML data. I need to get just the "2" from it, using BeautifulSoup4:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <small>3</small>
</td>
```

I tried:

```
k.find('rowspan')['style']
```

Which produced the exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Is it possible to do it using BS4? Or shouls I use a different library to extract CSS directly?

Comment: Please tell me if I have changed the meaning of your question as I struggled with the first part of it. Why are you using `k.find('rowspan')['style']` if what you're interested in is the value of the rowspan attribute? What is `k`? What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: k it's my html code taked by soup. It was first idea that I thought. I'm beginning my adventure with python and bs4. So what should I use to get attrib of rowspan?

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** that you are really using the `find` method, and **not** the `findall` method? Because the [`find` method never returns lists, only `None` if it doesn't find any matching tag](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).

Answer (score 1):

**Why are you using `find("rowspan")`? You are not searching for a `<rowspan>` tag.**

The [`find` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) searches for tags based on the **tag name** when a single string parameter is passed.

What you should be using is something like this, which means, "find the first `<td>` tag with attribute value `rowspan="2"`, and return the value of its `style` attribute":

```
k.find('td', rowspan="2")['style']
```

See the ["Kinds of filters"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) section of the docs for the various ways of specify which tags to search for.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><small>3</small></td>', 'html.parser')
print(soup.td['rowspan'])
```